# Uso de CPU sem uma explicação

Tags: sql-server

em nosso banco de dados usamos para relatorio o Performance Dashboard Reports, e estamos recebendo este tipo de pico..
o que nos incomoda é a questão da barra laranja.
Alguem sabe como podemos fazer para descobrir o que está elevando tanto a CPU?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A pergunta é sobre administração de banco de dados, tarefa típica de DBA. Sugiro que poste a dúvida em fórum específico: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/pt-BR/home?forum=admingeralpt

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão